# Printing every variable to a file

Tags: c, arrays, file

Good afternoon. I'm printing to a file but having a bit of problems. First of all, the program reads from a file, stores the contents in variables and prints to another file with a bit of additional information. The problem however, it only prints to new file the last person's information in the first file. If anyone is able to fix this I'm greatly thankful. Below is a snippet of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int idArray[100];
int AmtArray; //stores the number of ID's in array

int Stud_List();
//FUNCTION TO PRINT STUDENT'S LIST
int Stud_List(){    
    //DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
    FILE *kfile;
    char ffname[28];
    char flname[28];
    int fID;
    int x; //counts amount of entries within file

    //INITIALIZATION OF VARIABLES
    x = 0; 

    if ((kfile = fopen("information.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        //this to be displayed if file path is incorrect or file cannot be found.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file (%d: %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
        return 0;
    }

    while (!feof(kfile)){

        fscanf(kfile, "%s %s %d", ffname, flname, &fID); //reads the contents of the file
        printf("\n\n%s - %s - %d", ffname ,flname, fID);
        idArray[x] = fID;
        x++;
    }
    AmtArray = x;
}

int Stats( char *, int);
int Stats (*status, int id){ 

    FILE *Register;

    Register = fopen ("update.txt","w");
    fprintf( Register, "%5d%8s", id, status);

    fclose(Register);
    }

int main (void){
    int IDentry;
    int x, y; //counters in ID check
    printf("            ========Attendance Recording System========\n");
    printf("                              Menu\n");

    Stud_List(); //call to the function to print the list of the students

    printf("\n\n");
    for (x = 0; x < AmtArray; x++){

        printf("Please enter ID for absent student: ");
        scanf("%4d[0123456789]", &IDentry);

        if (IDentry == idArray[x]){
            Stats ("Absent", idArray[x]);
        }
        if (IDentry == idArray[x]){
            Stats ("Absent", idArray[x]);
        }
    }
getch();
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: feof() is only valid AFTER trying to read past the end of file, so should not be used as a loop control,

Comment: this line: 'int Stats (*status, int id){ ' should be 'int Stats (char *status, int id){ '  as both a prototype and the declaration must have all parameter types listed.  (the prototype does not need the parameter names, although including the names is a good documentation habit)

Comment: getch() and conio.h are not available everywhere, and not portable.  suggest using getchar() and stdlib.h

Comment: why is the code block, beginning with: ' if (IDentry == idArray[x]){' repeated?

Comment: The local variable: 'IDentry' is being used, but never set'

Comment: the code is missing #include <string.h> for the strerror() function  in main(), variable 'y' is not used

Comment: function: Stats() says it returns an 'int' but there is no 'return value' statement,  function: Stud_List() says it returns an 'int' but there is no ' return value' statement

Comment: 'register' is a reserved word in C, the code should not use the same name (even with a capitalization difference)  This will compile, but is very bad programming practice.

Comment: file 'information.txt' was opened in Stud_List()  but never closed

Comment: the returned value from fscanf() (and family) should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operations were successful.  in this case, if the returned value is != 3, the fscanf() failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Register = fopen ("update.txt","w");
```

It clears the file every time the file is opened. The 2nd parameter should be changed into `"a"` so every calls to `Stats()` append to the end of file.

Comment: Either that, or open the file *once* in `main` and pass it as an argument to `stats`.